# Are there other comic book characters that stayed dead?

Tags: marvel, comics

According to Wikipedia, there was once a common expression that "the only people who stay dead in comics are Bucky, Jason Todd, and Uncle Ben." By now, the first two were also resurrected. On the other hand, as far as I know, Gwen Stacy (of Earth 616) remained dead for good.

Of course, I'm sure that over the years there was a multitude of minor characters that died and remained dead. So let me formulate the question as follows:

**Are there other prominent comic book characters, in Earth 616 (Marvel), that have been dead for more than 10~15 years, and are still dead now?**

I realize that "prominent" is a bit subjective. I'm looking for characters that were an integral part of the life of a person who had their own title, like Gwen Stacy was to Peter Parker. (In fact, I'm not sure Uncle Ben himself counts, because I think he was dead before the title of Spider-Man began). Of course, if the very person with their own title died and remained dead (e.g. if Spider-Man or Captain America had not come back), that's even better.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/120562/58193) and [related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20363/58193).

Comment: The problem of 'prominency' is a hard one. An example: I'm not sure Jarella was an integral part of the Hulk's life. He loved her but they didn't spend much time together.

Comment: @fez I changed the formulation so that it won't be a list question.

Comment: @Ginasius You are right, this is definitely a bit of a problem with my question. I'd say that she in particular wasn't really prominent enough. Gwen was a major part of Peter's life, and he still thinks about her a lot even in today's comics.

Comment: Jonathan Kent? I don’t know, so not an answer, but seems likely.

Comment: @fez Asking for a list of characters that satisfy X in a *specific* universe is OK according the rules. I had a long discussion about this with The Lethal Carrot which is now deleted.

Comment: In any case I'm not asking for a list, but whether there is such a character.

Comment: Ah then it's an ["Is there any.." question in a specific universe](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12999) which is on topic

Comment: Without a better definition of "prominence", it's quite hard to see what a good answer would look like here.

Comment: Uncle Ben was killed in the first Spider Man story, indirectly because of Peter's action. I thought that they brought Gwen back years ago with the old, "we only killed a clone" gimic.

Comment: @NomadMaker Maybe I missed that, do you remember which comic it was?

Comment: @Wade I think I was wrong, in that a clone of Gwen was created many years after her death (complete with her memories); I thought this was the original. And isn't a clone of Ben one of the new spider men? (New by my lights, not most people.)

Comment: @NomadMaker Yes, there was recently a story where the Jackal and some clone of Peter Parker cloned many people Peter knew who died, including Gwen and Uncle Ben. But they weren't exactly resurrected, so it still counts in my book.

Comment: I don't recall a clone of Uncle Ben Parker ever becoming a Spider-Man...

Comment: @NomadMaker  - _"I thought that they brought Gwen back years ago with the old, "we only killed a clone" gimic."_ That wouldn't make any sense, since Gwen's death was the catalyst which motivated Miles Warren to become the Jackal and start creating clones in the first place. At the time of her death, he was just a college professor, not a supervillain, and hadn't made any clones yet. She was the first person he cloned.

Answer (score 7):

The original Thunderstrike, [Eric Masterson](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eric_Masterson_(Earth-616)), died in *[Thunderstrike Vol 1 #24](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thunderstrike_Vol_1_24)* (1995).

[image]

[image]

He and a number of other dead superheroes were briefly revived/reanimated as members of the [Legion of the Unliving](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Legion_of_the_Unliving_(Grim_Reaper)_(Earth-616)) in *[Avengers Vol 3 #10-11](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_3_10)* (1998), but they were laid to rest again at the end of the story, and Eric has remained dead ever since as far as I know.

[image]

[image]

His son, [Kevin](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kevin_Masterson_(Earth-616)), later inherited his [magical mace](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thunderstrike_(Item)) in *[Thunderstrike Vol 2 #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thunderstrike_Vol_2_1)* (2011), and became the second Thunderstrike.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(Updated)

**The Swordsman**

[Jacques DuQuesne](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jacques_Duquesne_(Earth-616)) a.k.a. the Swordsman was an early member of the Avengers. He died saving Mantis, whom he loved, from Kang the Conqueror. His body was later inhabited by the spirit of an elder Cotati (a plant species), but disintegrated when the Cotati left it. The Swordsman was briefly resurrected during the Chaos Wars, but perished permanently (so far) in #5, Janaury 2011, hence slightly more than 10 years ago.

[image]

**Captain Marvel (Genis-Vell)**

The son of the original Captain Marvel, Mar-vell, [Genis-Vell](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Genis-Vell_(Earth-616)https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Genis-Vell_(Earth-616)) assumed the name Captain Marvel after his father's death and appeared in a magazine of this name. He later joined the Thunderbolt, using the name Photon. However, Helmut Zemo caused his nega bands to fuse with his body and rage out of control, becoming a threat to the entire universe. Finally, Zemo used the Moonstones to kill Genis by sending his body parts into separate parts of the Darkforce Dimension so that they could never be rejoined. This happened in *Thunderbolts* #6, May 2005, and Genis hasn't been resurrected since.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The original Captain Marvel was an iconic death of the early marvel universe (Feb 1982). As far as I know (and [wikipedia seems to confirm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(Mar-Vell))) he was never resurrected for more than a discussion e.g. with Thanos or a short arc like the unliving.

[image]

Comment: I answered with the same character yesterday but his brief resurrection in Secret Avengers 26 (2012) discarded him in OP's opinion. By the way, Thanos is not his brother. Mar-vell is a kree and Thanos is from Titan, Jupiter's moon. Maybe you were thinking in Starfox, a different character.

Comment: my bad for the brother part, mixing myself up with starfox I guess. Something a about mar-vell dying and being buried on Titan must have confused me. Honestly the fact marvel is dead is a big "thing" for a long time in the marvel universe of 80'/90's. References to it keep coming back in other comics. I haven't really read many comics post 2005, so if he's been resurrected in 2012 I wouldn't know about it.

Comment: I thought that Mar-Vell remained dead since 1982 too but that's not the case. He was revived just for a few issues that I didn't know either.

Comment: Wonder Man?  Also, over in the DC universe, Ferro Lad stayed dead for a really long time.